# Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL and it throws the error Ambiguous column name 'id'

```
select tbl_registration.*, tbl_ebp.name as ebp_name, tbl_Users.id as user_id, tbl_ebp.id as linked_ebp_id
from tbl_registration
left outer join tbl_ebp on tbl_ebp.id = tbl_registration.ebp_id
left outer join tbl_users on tbl_registration.email = tbl_users.username
where id = [PARAM]p_id
```

I've read some articles on this, but can't find a working solution for my code.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your WHERE clause id needs to be more specific, include the table name:

```
WHERE table.id = [PARAM]p_id
```

If two things share the same name, this is where the ambiguity steps in.  In this case multiple tables in your SQL contain the "id" column.

SQL has the intelligence to disambiguate column names if the column name is unique across the current set of tables being touched - hence most of the time you don't need to prefix column names with table names.

Comment: Personally I prefer to always specify which table the field came from. This makes maintenance much easier especially when dealing with complex reporting type queries that join to ten differnt tables. That way I know where the field came from if it is the one that is giving me a problem without having to look up the structure of ten differnt tables to find out where it came from.

Answer (score 6):

most likely more than one table has a column named id; use a table prefix in the where clause

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried prefixing the id column name in the where clause?

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to "id" in your where clause.  You need to specify which table's "id" it should filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced your code

```
select *, tbl_ebp.name as ebp_name, tbl_Users.id as user_id, tbl_ebp.id as linked_ebp_id
from tbl_registration
left outer join tbl_ebp on tbl_ebp.id = tbl_registration.ebp_id
left outer join tbl_users on tbl_registration.email = tbl_users.username
where your_respective_tblname.id = your_respective_tblname.[PARAM]p_id
```