# Laravel 5.5 - How to fetch related products in many to many relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

[image]I am developing a e-commerce website.

I have 3 tables

1.**prodcts table**

2.**conditions table**

3.**condition_product table**

- A product can have many conditions.
- particular condition belongs to many products.

Now I have a product which belongs to 3 conditions.

I want to get all related products which belongs to these 3 conditions.

How can i achieve this?

**product.php**

```
public function conditions(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Condition::class)->withTimestamps();

}
```

**condition.php**

```
public function products(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withTimestamps();

}
```

This is my code:

```
 public function productDetails(Product $product)
{
    $a = $product->id;

   $relatedProducts = Product::whereHas('conditions.products', function($q) use($a) {
        $q->where('id', $a);
    })
        ->get();


    return view('pages/product', compact('product','relatedProducts'));
}
```

But I am getting error.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?? include it in your question, it will help others to understand better

Comment: is it really your full code??

Comment: I included the error screenshot on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method with nested relationships:

```
Product::whereHas('conditions.products', function($q) use($productId) {
    $q->where('id', $productId);
})
->get();
```

This will give you products that have conditions of a specified product.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
$conditionIds = Product::find($productId)->conditions->pluck('id');
$products = Product::whereHas('conditions', function($q) use($conditionIds) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $conditionIds);
})
->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. I am getting error like this

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p are you talking about the first solution? Just tried in 5.3, works fine. Also, please make sure you do not modify the code. Just copy paste it and use.

Comment: Yeah, For first solution I got that error, I am using 5.5

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p I don't think they changed something between 5.3 and 5.5. Please show the actual code you're using when you get the error.

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p and what `dd($product->id)` gives you? Integer like `5`?

Comment: Yeah I am getting integer  value for that(i got 2 which is my product id).

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p then everything looks fine to me. Please show what SQL from the error message.

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p the SQL query in the error is different, but I'm not sure why because relationships you've shown look fine.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your time. I will try

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p if you'll find the issue, please tell me about it.

Comment: If id is ambigious, try $q->where('products.id', $productId); or whatever id the problem is

Comment: yeah, That was the problem i have edited the answer know, Thank you

Comment: @Inuyaki thank you. But it's still weird since the raw SQL query is different from mine.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to always specify witch table the 'id' field is referencing too, because if not, it could both reference the 'conditions' table or the 'products' table 'id' field :

```
$relatedProducts = Product::whereHas('conditions.products', function($q) use($a) {
        $q->where('products.id', $a);
    })
    ->get();
```

You could see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230023/ambiguous-column-name) about SQL ambiguous column name.